# Variable scope interfering with DSL in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
module Typecast
  class DSL
    def self.call(&blk)
      new.instance_eval(&blk)
    end
    def new_age(val)
      p val
    end
  end

  def typecast(&blk)
    DSL.call(&blk)
  end
  private :typecast
end

class Person
  include Typecast
  def age=(new_age)
    typecast do
      new_age :integer
    end
  end
end

Person.new.age = 10

# test.rb:33: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
#       new_age :integer
```

Ruby returns this error because it knows `new_age` is a local variable defined in the method arguments. So when I change the `Person` class to this:

```
class Person
  include Typecast
  def age=(new_val)
    typecast do
      new_age :integer
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby now returns the expected `:integer`.

My question is, how do I stop local variables from interfering with `instance_eval` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a variable and a method with the same name both existing in the same scope, the way to disambiguate is to clarify the receiver. In this case, you want the receiver to be `self`:

```
class Person
  include Typecast
  def age=(new_age)
    typecast do
      self.new_age :integer    # Avoids ambiguity because we used an
    end                        # explicit receiver.
  end
end

Person.new.age = 10
# => :integer
# => 10
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this. I was wondering if there was a way to avoid having to do this. I want to change the binding/scope of the `typecast` block